# Getting Id in Subquery

Tags: database, oracle, subquery, oracle-apex

I've been working on an auction site in APEX. For the auction site I need to make an overview that shows which products have been bought by someone. Pretty sure it's just something I forgot but how can I obtain the result in the following situation:

**3 Tables**

```
Table User
USER_ID
EMAIL

Table Product
PRODUCT_ID
USER_ID

Table Bid
BID_ID
PRODUCT_ID
USER_ID
CREDITS
```

Ofcourse there are more columns but I think leaving them out makes the explenation slightly easier.

**Needed Result**

Displaying products from the Product table. But only if the current user has the highest bid (Credits).

**So far**

I've been thinking/trying a lot on this one but keep getting killed at the end of the subqueries.

```
SELECT *
FROM "PRODUCT"
WHERE "PRODUCT_ID" IN (SELECT "PRODUCT_ID" FROM "BID"
                      WHERE "USER_ID" = 
                      (SELECT "USER_ID" FROM "USER"
                      WHERE lower("EMAIL") = lower(:APP_USER)))
  and "PRODUCT_ID" = (SELECT "PRODUCT_ID" FROM "BID"
                      WHERE "CREDITS" =
                     (SELECT MAX("CREDITS") FROM "BID"
                      WHERE "PRODUCT_ID" = ?
```

*Apex returns the Emailadress from the current user (:APP_USER)

The real problem starts at the "and" as the user filtering works fine. I have no idea how to get the compared (current) PRODUCT_ID in the subquery. I'm pretty sure that if I get that value at the end of the subquery it'll work.

Working with Oracle DB.

Any help appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this..

```
SELECT *
FROM PRODUCT p
WHERE p.PRODUCT_ID IN (SELECT PRODUCT_ID FROM BID"
                      WHERE "USER_ID" = 
                      (SELECT "USER_ID" FROM "USER"
                      WHERE lower("EMAIL") = lower(:APP_USER)))
  and "PRODUCT_ID" =  (SELECT "PRODUCT_ID" FROM "BID" b
                      WHERE "CREDITS" =
                     (SELECT MAX("CREDITS") FROM "BID"
                      WHERE b.PRODUCT_ID" = p.product_id));
```

or

```
and "PRODUCT_ID" in (SELECT "PRODUCT_ID" FROM "BID" b
                      WHERE "CREDITS" =
                     (SELECT MAX("CREDITS") FROM "BID"
                      WHERE b.PRODUCT_ID" = p.product_id))
```

Comment: Worked excellent, for those who check out this question: Do note there's a missing quote in the first code part :) Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
SELECT
    p.*
FROM
    Bid b
    JOIN
    -- get the max bid per product
    (SELECT
        PRODUCT_ID, MAX(CREDITS) AS MAX_C
    FROM
        Bid
    GROUP BY
        PRODUCT_ID) m ON b.PRODUCT_ID = m.PRODUCT_ID AND b.CREDITS = m.CREDITS
    JOIN USER u ON b.USER_ID = u.USER_ID
    JOIN Product p ON b.PRODUCT_ID = p.PRODUCT_ID
WHERE
    lower(u.EMAIL) = lower(:APP_USER)));
```

Note that you may have issues if the credits on the bid are not unique per product (but that should be a business rule in your auction anyways).

**EDIT**

From a query length perspective, the following is probably better as it ensures that you are only checking for wins on the products that the user has actually ever bid on, as opposed to above which checks all products ever.

```
SELECT
    p.*
FROM
    Bid b
    JOIN
    -- get the max bid per product that the user bid on
    (SELECT
        PRODUCT_ID, MAX(CREDITS) AS MAX_C
    FROM
        Bid b2
        JOIN (
            -- get only the products that the user has bid on
            SELECT
                DISTINCT b1.PRODUCT_ID
            FROM
                Bid b1
                JOIN User u1 ON b1.USER_ID = u1.USER_ID
            WHERE
                lower(u1.EMAIL) = lower(:APP_USER))) dp
        ON b2.PRODUCT_ID = dp.PRODUCT_ID
    GROUP BY
        PRODUCT_ID) m ON b.PRODUCT_ID = m.PRODUCT_ID AND b.CREDITS = m.CREDITS
    JOIN USER u ON b.USER_ID = u.USER_ID
    JOIN Product p ON b.PRODUCT_ID = p.PRODUCT_ID
WHERE
    lower(u.EMAIL) = lower(:APP_USER)));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering, while I went with the other answer I've tried this one aswell and found it working aswell :) Thanks for the help!